# React 'style' conflict with Django template(?)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, django, django-templates, babeljs

So I'm using python django as well as inline babel script (React). Now my problem is I think that React's style `style={{ height : '100px' }}` conflicts with Django templates.

I tried using djangos verbatim tag but still no luck.